# Office365 Application Accounts

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I'm having great difficulty in finding out how I'm supposed to do this. I have applications that need to send e-mails form our domain.

I've had a suggestion to use shared accounts, but I don't think you can log in as a shared e-mail account (ex: myApp@myDomain.com), and let alone all of my applications would share a password (ack!).

Do I have to purchase mailboxes for every service and application account? Is there a way to run a non-human user account?

Comment: You don't have to relay through exchange online to send from your domain. Just build an SMTP relay service local to the applications and make sure it's in your SPF record.

Answer (score 2):

Shared Accounts won't work, as you will be unable to login into them. Shared Accounts can only be added as another mailbox to a full user account.

You can purchase a mailbox for each service, but that's not really the way to do it, you'll be paying a lot and the operation of those accounts will be a headache.

SMTP Relay is what you need, you'll configure your local apps to send to the relay, and the relay server will take care of mail delivery for you. Here's a very nice detailed step by step link on how to enable it with tools for testing: http://o365info.com/smtp-relay-in-office-365-environment/